# Sort documents based on matched inner nested objects in Elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

I am working on a sort query for my documents in the index. Here are the documents look like:

```
{
    "studentId": "123",
    "studentName": "Frodo",
    "year": "2023",
    "Scores": [{
            "subject": "Physics",
            "score": "100"
        },
        {
            "subject": "Chemistry",
            "score": "700"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "studentId": "456",
    "studentName": "Samwise",
    "year": "2023",
    "Scores": [{
            "subject": "Physics",
            "score": "200"
        },
        {
            "subject": "Chemistry",
            "score": "600"
        }
    ]
}
```

```
{
    "studentId": "789",
    "studentName": "Merry",
    "year": "2023",
    "Scores": [{
            "subject": "Physics",
            "score": "300"
        },
        {
            "subject": "Chemistry",
            "score": "500"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get results in descending order that falls in the range. For example, I am running following query

```
{
    "size": 10000,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                    "term": {
                        "year": "2023"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "Scores.score": {
                            "lte": 200
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "sort": [{
        "Scores.score": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }]
}
```

with the above query, I am getting the 2 docs as expected but I am getting doc with '100' score first instead of '200'. I think when ES is performing the sort, it is picking up 700 first and 600 next and giving the documents in that order. How can I do the query that sorts only on matched inner fields? In this case, the sorting should consider only 200, 100 scores and ignore others. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

I have tried the sort mode option with `min` mode. It works with this particular example but it doesn't work with different scenario. For example, if I use the score as 800 in the same query with `min` mode, I am getting doc3 (score 300 and 500) as response but I expect doc1(score 100 and 700) since 700 is highest score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all I think you have wrong mapping. For this to work, the "Scores" field should be declared as [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html). In order to filter by the score you need to use [nested query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html). And finally in order to sort by that score you need to use [nested sort](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.9/sort-search-results.html#nested-sorting) with the same filter that you used in the nested query. If you combine all this together you will get something like this:

```
PUT test
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 0,
    "number_of_shards": 1
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "studentId": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "studentName": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "year": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "Scores": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "subject": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "score": {
            "type": "long"
          }

        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST test/_bulk?refresh
{"index":{}}
{"studentId":"123","studentName":"Frodo","year":"2023","Scores":[{"subject":"Physics","score":"100"},{"subject":"Chemistry","score":"700"}]}
{"index":{}}
{"studentId":"456","studentName":"Samwise","year":"2023","Scores":[{"subject":"Physics","score":"200"},{"subject":"Chemistry","score":"600"}]}
{"index":{}}
{"studentId":"789","studentName":"Merry","year":"2023","Scores":[{"subject":"Physics","score":"300"},{"subject":"Chemistry","score":"500"}]}

POST test/_search
{
  "size": 10000,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "year": "2023"
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "Scores",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "Scores.score": {
                  "lte": 200
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    {
      "Scores.score": {
        "mode": "max",
        "order": "asc",
        "nested": {
          "path": "Scores",
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "Scores.score": {
                "lte": 200
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```